# Issue with @Value and application.properties since moving to Spring Boot 1.1.4.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am having an issue since I moved to version 1.1.4.RELEASE of Spring Boot.

My variables that are annotated with @Value are presently not being populated with values despite them being present in the application.properties. Prior to this I was using Spring Boot @ version 1.0.2, and that was working fine.

It all started since the upgrade, and I made no code change.

SampleApplication.java

```
package org.sample;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties")
public class SampleApplication {

private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(TaskManagerApplication.class);

@Value("${org.sample.sampleProperty}")
private static String sampleProperty;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SpringApplication.run(SampleApplication.class, args);
    System.out.print("SampleApplication started: " + sampleProperty);

}

@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {

    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();

}
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mydb
spring.datasource.username: root
spring.datasource.password: root
spring.datasource.driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql: true

#Disable the ddl-auto:create once tables have been created
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: create

org.sample.sampleProperty=This is a sample property

photos.upload.dir=C:/temp/UserPhotos/

# Server port
server.port=8081
```

I have tried to add a PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer bean and even PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer but still the issue persists.

Anyone experienced this ? Or is there a new way to load the properties file ?

Please note that my db connection and server port are being read properly since my application can connect to db and I have to access it through the specified port. 
sampleProperty variable remains null though.

Comment: Why do you declare a `@PropertySource`? this should work out of the box (i.e. without the `@PropertySource` and the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` bean

Comment: yes I know. I was using without `@PropertySource` and `@PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` . I tried these after experiencing this issue, but to no avail :(

Comment: `@Value` (like `@Autowired) doesn't work on static fields afaik. If this worked, on static fields, I would say that that was unintentional.

Comment: I tried using both version of Spring Boot that you mentioned and neither worked. It makes sense that I didn't work since you are trying to inject values into a static field

Comment: Also having this issue w/ 1.1.5 and 1.1.6 - anyone know if this is supported? (ie- is this a bug or feature?)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. `@Value` is not meant to work on static fields
2. Properties from `application.properties` are available automatically without specifying `@PropertySource` for it.
3. Instead of printing out property in `main()` method, you should do it after bean is constructed, for example by using `@PostConstruct`

Fully working example:

```java
package demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    @Value("${org.sample.sampleProperty}")
    private String sampleProperty;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        System.out.print("SampleApplication started: " + sampleProperty);
    }
}
```

Comment: This prints to my console with the value. But when I open up localhost it becomes null?